Logistics of a mountaintop city
So looking at a city located on a mountaintop or a mountain plateau (think Machu Picchu), how would the city logistics works? Most cities had immediate farmland to provide food, but how could a mountaintop city solve food issues (I already have ideas on water, mind you)?
NOTE: We are talking about specifically medieval city here; EDIT2: population of some 15 000 people or so, if possible.

Thinking Machu Pichu: The city received a lot of rain, which was collected, and had extensive terraced gardens for food production. It had so much water from rainfall, in fact, that the engineers had to make drainage systems so that the gardens were not drowned. -- wikipedia

The rock of Aornos seemed to have cultivated areas within the fortified precinct. I picture it s/what similar to Machu Pichu, only military from the onstart. Aornos might be the Greek transliteration of a name which evolved into the modern Una Sar.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aornos

I've gotta down vote for lack of research. You even mention Machu Picchu. Did you not research how that city's logistics operated? What did you not learn from that research? Explaining it all to you is a big bite (probably a violation of the Book Rule, see [help/dont-ask]) so the value of research is the ability to narrow your question to fit inside of Stack Exchange's expectations (see [ask]).

I have researched Machu Picchu, but you apparently fail to realize that Macchu Pichu is not a city, but a citadel - with estimated population of 750. City I was thinking of is closer to actual medieval city size - so several thousand people at least. That is an apples and oranges comparison, so I really do not see why you would even bring it up.
I am asking about a mountain city here, not mountain village. Sorry if I was not clear.

The main reason to build a city on a mountaintop - other than religion - is for its defensive value, in that attacking uphill in a pre-modern era is exhausting and difficult.
However, as the OP has stated, this makes the logistics difficult.  A militarily defensive city would need plenty of storage for food  as well as having a good supply of water, so that in the event of a siege that would necessarily cut off the supply of food, the city could hold out long enough for the siege to be lifted.
At least initially, such a city (or town at the time) would be supplied by porters and draft animals walking up and down, carrying the necessary supplies.  However, while that might work for a town, the more people that come to inhabit the settlement, the greater the demand for supplies.  Some alternative means of transport would be advisable.
The necessities of supplying such a city could fall to a railway.  Historically, railways appeared in the medieval era, mostly in mines, but there are examples of early vertical railways, such as the Reisszug.  A vertical railway with a counterweight could make the task of transporting supplies up the mountain much easier.  Transporting waste down the mountain on the counterweight would enhance the counterweight aspect of a vertical railway.

Note that medieval technology could only make ropes a couple hundred meters long, so a vertical railway could help for a short slope, but not a long incline. If you think about modern use cases of cableways, you would almost always need industrial age steel cables. (Even the shortest of the funiculars going up Vomera hill in Naples, Chiaia, has a length of 500 meters, which could not be realised with a hemp rope.)

A system of Erdstalls.
These are tunnels, not big, just a man-height or less.
Assuming an act of religious devotion or a war.
They could be held open in addition to the usual rope-lifts, mountain paths and tiered crop-growth.
They would be navigated by crawling, then standing to hoist yourself up into a higher tunnel. This would be done whilst dragging grain or other vegetable-stuffs, trailing the odd box of chicken eggs (ready for hatching), or maybe even with a goat or two in tow.
Thus caves within the mountain would be stocked with foodstuffs, fuel for lighting, and much fertilizer could be gleaned from the chicken-poop - either for resale or for the manufacture of gunpowder if your civilisation has a use for it.
At the base, these would be easily defensible from the inside, dropping big rocks to seal the entrance as the Pharos once did. Some entrances would be through a further tunnel leading far from the base of the cliff allowing for concealed entry during siege. (See: underground tunnel for inspiration there.)

Terraces
Terraces could provide agriculture- so the fact that the city is on a mountain top does not mean they wouldn't have agriculture.
One thing that would help get items up and down the mountain are the irrigation ditches.  According to the Wikipedia entry on terraces in South America:
"South America
Diagram showing Inca terrace engineering for agriculture.
In the South American Andes, farmers have used terraces, known as andenes, for over a thousand years to farm potatoes, maize, and other native crops. Terraced farming was developed by the Wari culture and other peoples of the south-central Andes before 1000 AD, centuries before they were used by the Inca, who adopted them. The terraces were built to make the most efficient use of shallow soil and to enable irrigation of crops by allowing runoff to occur through the outlet.[9]
The Inca people built on these, developing a system of canals, aqueducts, and puquios to direct water through dry land and increase fertility levels and growth.[10] These terraced farms are found wherever mountain villages have existed in the Andes. They provided the food necessary to support the populations of great Inca cities and religious centres such as Machu Picchu."
